# ACTION_GET_CONTENT. can't select file

Tags: android, kotlin

After copying the text file created on the PC to Android, try to open the file.

However, when I try to open it with ACTION_GET_CONTENT, the file I have already opened is visible on the initial screen, but it cannot be selected, and I have to go to my file folder to open it.

Was it originally like that?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Main Activity**

```
Dexter.withContext(this)
        .withPermissions(
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ).withListener(object :
        MultiplePermissionsListener {
        override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport) { /* ... */ }
        override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(permissions: List<PermissionRequest>, token: PermissionToken) { /* ... */ } }).check()

private val _reqArticleMaster = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
    if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val url = it.data?.data
        val takeFlags = (intent.flags
                and (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION))
        contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(url!!, takeFlags)

        val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        contentResolver.openInputStream(url)?.use { inputStream ->
            BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {
                val json = it.readText()
                val array =
                    Gson().fromJson(json, Array<ArticleMaster>::class.java).toList()
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    Repository.articleMasterDao.insert(array)
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "제품마스터 수신성공", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
                        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                        type = "*/*"
                    }
                    _reqArticleMaster.launch(intent)
```

[image]

[image]

**Can't select file on initial screen.**

[image: Can't select file]

**Can select file on /Internal storage/[MyFolder]/[MyFile]**

[image]

Comment: You do not need any of those storage permissions if you use ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: Also there are no permanent uri permissions for ACTION_GET_CONTENT so it does not make sense trying to take them.